why is there sometimes "a particular" and then a person's name?
for example,
"I am writing this letter to a particular Mrs. Smith"
or
"I believe a particular Jane Doe is looking for you, sir!"
Why is the phrase "a particular" there and what purpose does it serve?

Do you have an example of where this is written?

Particular = specific.

It means it's their actual name, not a placeholder. Other examples are Joe Bloggs, Tommy Atkins (both UK), and Jim Crow (US).

It's a "less than idiomatic" version of I am writing this letter to one Mrs. Smith. Asked previously on ELU, but not formally answered

How is this any different from I once received a letter from a certain Daniel Webster?

Does this answer your question? What does "submit for your inspection one John H. Watson" mean?

But if we say "I was contacted by a certain John J. Jingleheimer-Schmidt", it means by a person of that name who was otherwise unknown to me.

I'm going to second @FumbleFingers' proposed duplicate because the answer is that this usage works the same way.

The word “particular” here is meant to imply that the letter or person that is coming will be exciting to the recipient.

The difference between a comment and an answer is that the answer should be descriptive.
